# Original ZIP size limits 2^32 vs 2^32 - 1. Is there an off by 1 error in Wikipedia?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, deflate

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#ZIP64

> The original .ZIP format had a 4 GB (2^32 bytes) limit on various things (uncompressed size of a file, compressed size of a file, and total size of the archive), as well as a limit of 65,535 (2^16-1) entries in a ZIP archive.

Is the 2^32 value correct? By my understanding, the maximum value should be the maximum possible value held in a 32 bit unsigned integer, which is 2^32-1

I know that 2^32-1 does have particular meaning according to the ZIP spec at https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT (usually mentioned as 0xFFFFFFFF), so I don't want to assume anything.

The 2^16-1 limit for number of entries *does* seem right to me, as the maximum value that can be stored in a 16 bit unsigned integer.

Context: I'm writing code to write ZIP files in a streaming way in Python https://github.com/uktrade/stream-zip, as well code to open ZIP files in a streaming way https://github.com/uktrade/stream-unzip, and I want both to handle the various limits correctly. Or if not "correctly" (say if there is no "correctly") as best as is reasonable.

Comment: Why is this posted here and not asked/edited on Wikipedia?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Asking about the limits in the ZIP format seems reasonable to me for here? Including linking to Wikipedia since it shows a bit of research. And I guess I deliberately framed it as “is Wikipedia wrong” in order to try to invoke answers correcting me!

Comment: Have you posted an edit request to Wikipedia? If not, that is likely where this issue should start.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No, I haven’t. I guess to me that’s an optional second step… posting here to become sure on the limit seems better than editing Wikipedia when I’m not sure.

Comment: And I would do the exact opposite. Why would anyone reviewing that Wikipedia article decide to come here? Which action would have the most beneficial effect on the computing society as a whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mix up a few things in that sentence, but the limits were 2<sup>32</sup>–1 compressed bytes as well as 2<sup>32</sup>–1 uncompressed bytes in a single entry, and a start-of-central-directory offset of 2<sup>32</sup>–1. And, as stated, 2<sup>16</sup>–1 entries.

Note that the limit on the central-directory offset permits a zip file *larger* than 4 GiB, but not much larger. So the "total size of the archive" limit mentioned in the Wikipedia page is neither 4 GiB nor 4 GiB – 1. The sentence would need to be broken up to provide exactly correct information.

Comment: Thanks! Also on "not much larger"... I _think_ I've managed to make a Zip 2.0 file that's just shy of 8GiB: https://gist.github.com/michalc/eb43718fcf1d5d8285e2c9c7fe97d409 . And I wonder if some "extra" data can be added into the central directory records and get even closer to 8GiB

Comment: Is a 12G central directory really possible? Looking at https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT it looks like the size of the central directory has to fit into 4 bytes, so has an upper bound of 2^32-1 = 4G-1?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Though the central directory length information is superfluous and ignored, with the number of entries being used instead to know when the directory ends. So a 16GiB non-Zip64 zip file would still work.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise it was ignored! Thank you :-)

Comment: Yes, even with a correct central-directory length, you can go over 8 GiB with the end-of-central-directory record. You can even put a 64 KiB-1 zip file comment in there for good measure. The largest, fully legal, non-Zip64 zip archive size is then 8 GiB + 65555 bytes = 4 GiB - 1 byte of local entries + 4 GiB - 1 byte of central directory + 22 byte end of central directory record + 64 KiB - 1 byte comment.

Answer (score 0):

Elsewhere on the same Wikipedia page includes the minus 1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Limits

> The maximum size for both the archive file and the individual files inside it is 4,294,967,295 bytes (2^32−1 bytes, or 4 GB minus 1 byte) for standard ZIP.

Also in the ZIP specification at https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT, there are various mentions of the size fields being 4 bytes, e.g.

```
4.4.8 compressed size: (4 bytes)
4.4.9 uncompressed size: (4 bytes)
```

and the largest values that can be stored in these are 2^32−1

And in the same spec, it says:

```
Maximum .ZIP segment size = 4,294,967,295 bytes
```

which is 2^32-1 (I guess applicable for single-segment ZIP files?  Edit: This apparently isn't applicable, as per comments below )

So I think yes, there is an off by one error in the ZIP64 section, and the maximum size *is* 2^32 - 1

Comment: At least one of them must be wrong, but it seems a bit of a stretch to assume one of them must be right without further evidence.

Comment: @tripleee I've put a bit more information as to why I think this is the case. But... I certainly invite other, better, answers!

Comment: No, the segment limit does not apply to non-split zip files.